How to Integrate Ckeditor4-react and ckfinder3?
My project runs on react, and I'm trying to integrate CKFinder3 and Ckeditor4-react but I found nothing useful for react from the doc: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_ckfinder_integration.html
I searched on the internet and below is my code, the editor is ok but CKFinder does not work, Does anyone here know what I'm missing and how to integrate them?
import React from "react";
import { CKEditor } from "ckeditor4-react";

export default function HtmlEditor() {
    const editorConfig = {
        autoParagraph: false,
        allowedContent: true,
        extraPlugins: "bidi, colorbutton, floatpanel, font, imagemaps, justify, panelbutton, showblocks, switchbar",
        toolbar: "Full",
        fullPage: true,
        ckfinder: {
            startupPath: "Libraries/ckfinder/3.4.1/",
            options: {
                resourceType: "Images",
            },
        },
    };


    return <CKEditor config={editorConfig} data="This is an example CKEditor 4 WYSIWYG editor instance." />;
}

